# no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘*(myCache + ((long unsigned int)(((long unsigned int)i) * 32ul)))

Tags: c++, linux

I keep getting an error below:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:41: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘*(myCache + ((long unsigned int)(((long unsigned int)i) * 32ul))) = (Cache*)operator new [](((size_t)(((long unsigned int)ASSOC) * 32u)))’
cache.h:2: note: candidates are: Cache& Cache::operator=(const Cache&)
main.cpp:47: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘*(myCache + ((long unsigned int)(((long unsigned int)i) * 32ul)))[j]’
main.cpp:50: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘*(myCache + ((long unsigned int)(((long unsigned int)i) * 32ul)))[j]’
main.cpp:52: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘*(myCache + ((long unsigned int)(((long unsigned int)i) * 32ul)))[j]’
main.cpp:53: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘*(myCache + ((long unsigned int)(((long unsigned int)i) * 32ul)))[j]’
main.cpp:54: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘*(myCache + ((long unsigned int)(((long unsigned int)i) * 32ul)))[j]’
main.cpp:55: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘*(myCache + ((long unsigned int)(((long unsigned int)i) * 32ul)))[j]’
```

The code is as below:

```
int main() {
    int ASSOC, BLOCKSIZE, NO_SETS, SIZE, i, k, l, j;
    int NO_INDEXB, NO_BLOCKB, NO_TAGB;

    cout << "Please enter Block Size: " << '\n';
    cin >> BLOCKSIZE;
    cout << " Please enter size: " << '\n';
    cin >> SIZE;
    cout << " Please enter Associativity: " << '\n';
    cin >> ASSOC;

    NO_SETS = SIZE / (ASSOC * BLOCKSIZE);
    // cout << "No of Sets: " << NO_SETS << '\n';

    NO_INDEXB = int(log2(NO_SETS));
    // cout << NO_INDEXB <<endl;

    NO_BLOCKB = int(log2(BLOCKSIZE));
    // cout << NO_BLOCKB <<endl;

    NO_TAGB = BLOCKSIZE - NO_INDEXB - NO_BLOCKB;
    // cout << NO_TAGB <<endl;

    Cache* myCache;
    myCache = new Cache[NO_SETS];
    for (i = 0; i < NO_SETS; i++)
        myCache[i] = new Cache[ASSOC];

    for (i = 0; i < NO_SETS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ASSOC; j++) {
            myCache[i][j].tag = new char(NO_TAGB + 1);
            for (k = 0; k < NO_TAGB; k++) {
                myCache[i][j].tag[k] = '0';
            }
            myCache[i][j].LRU = j;
            myCache[i][j].valid = 0;
            myCache[i][j].dirty = 0;
            myCache[i][j].index = i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: At the very least you should show how `Cache` is defined.

Comment: Use `std::vector<Cache>`, or `std::vector<std::vector<Cache>>` respectively.

Comment: hey i got the answer for it

Comment: Cache** myCache;
        myCache = new Cache*[NO_SETS];
 for (i=0;i<NO_SETS;i++)
   myCache[i]= new Cache[ASSOC];
adding ** helped me get rid of the error

Comment: It seems like you intended `myCache` to be a 2-D array ?

Comment: Pay attention to the difference between `[` and `(`.  `new char(x)` creates a single char whose value is `x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cache* myCache;

myCache[i][j].LRU = j;
```

what does `myCache[i][j]` means